# What does the checkbox "Trust access to the VBA Project Model" mean?

Tags: excel, vba, security, settings

"Trust access to the VBA project model" is something I instinctively click on right after "Enable all macros", simply because I don't have time to workout whether or not it will break the code I would like to run.

This is naughty - I should know what I'm doing and the implications. Assuming I've enabled all macros already, what extra features/dangers are exposed to me when I open the Pandora's Box of trusting access to the VBA project model?

This line of code runs without trusting access:

```
VBAProject.Sheet1.Calculate
```

Please would you post some code that *requires* trusted access?

Comment: Down voters care to comment? Why is a question about VBA macros considered "off-topic"?

Comment: @simoco This is a very specific programming question about a poorly documented and badly named switch. Why do you think it is about "general hardware and software"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It allows your code to access the VBA project by doing such things as reading and altering other code or changing the codenames of objects. Basically it controls access to the properties and methods of anything you access via the Workbook.VBProject property.

Comment: can you give me an example of some code that won't run without access being trusted?

Comment: Sure `msgbox activeworkbook.VBProject.Name` or `msgbox activeworkbook.VBProject.vbcomponents("Sheet1").CodeModule.CountOfLines` for example

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now. Sometimes I can't see the wood for the trees.#