# How to get Visual Basic to assign codenames for new sheets in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I want users of my workbook to be able to add new sheets to it, and for the sheet to automatically have a codename assigned to it for Visual Basic to use. I have noticed this works perfectly when a new sheet is added by 'copying' an existing sheet, but no codename gets assigned when you add a sheet using toolbar down the bottom, or when you add a sheet from another workbook - ie the codename is literally blank. I've scoured Google and found that opening the Visual Basic code refreshes the codenames and this is when it gets assigned, thus the code works from that point, however the last thing I want is the users having to open the code just so that the code works.

In my research I found people saying it is a bug in Excel, that yes the codename doesn't get assigned until you open the code, but with no real solution. There must be a way to trigger VB to assign the codenames without having to do this.

I note I found suggestions that require the code to access VB programmatically but I want to avoid that, as that's not a setting I want to enable on all the users' computers.

Your help would be much appreciated!

Comment: afaik, this cannot be done without  accessing VB programmatically.

Comment: put `MsgBox Sh.CodeName` in the workbook's `Workbook_NewSheet` sub and create a new sheet, you will see that a codename is assigned as "sheet1/2/3/4/etc". if you dont want to grant access to VBA Project model, your alternative is to create a hidden "dictionary" sheet where you give a custom nickname to each sheet thats being created, and in VBA whenever someone wants to reference a sheet by it's nickname he will have to consult the dictionary on the hidden sheet.

Comment: It would really help your question to include a small example code where this problem can be demonstrated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets.Add
ws.Name = "NewSheetName"
ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(ws.CodeName).Name = "NewSheetCodeName"
```

Comment: Thanks Olly, I gave that a try but it also requires programmatic access to Visual Basic

Comment: @mda13336 and how do you wish to achieve this without vba? And why is your question tagged `excel-vba` then???

Comment: @Rawrplus I think he means the ["Trust access to the VBA project model"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23536930/what-does-the-checkbox-trust-access-to-the-vba-project-model-mean) checkbox that allows access to `VBProject`, but is probably unchecked by default. There are probably some complicated ways around it but meh .. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cristib/2012/02/29/vba-how-to-programmatically-enable-access-to-the-vba-object-model-using-macros/